# Moving Robot Optimally down the grid

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is a maze of size `N*M`, consisting of unit blocks. At the start Robot has `R` percentage of battery charged. Now Robot start from 1st row and move towards Nth row. From the present block robot can move to a block in the next row, which is either on right or on left side of the present block. On moving to a block in ith row jth column, Robots battery charge will reduce by `C(i,j)` percent if `C(i,j)` is greater then 0, else it will be recharged by `C(i,j)` percent.

For Example if battery has 50 percent of charge, on moving to block with `C(i,j) = 15`, battery will have 35 ( 50 -15 ) percent of the charge.

Now we want to find out the status of the battery in the end, if the Robot moves optimally to save maximum charge.

Note : Battery Charge will not exceed more than 100 percent, and Robot will not move further if Battery charge goes down to 0 percent.

EXAMPLE : LET `N*M` grid be `4*4` as follow :

```
 10 -10 10 -10

-10 10 -10  10

 5  -5   5  -5

-5  -5  -5  -5
```

And if initial battery charged is 50(=R) then here answer will be 80 as One of the optimal move will be

```
<1,2> -> <2,1> -> <3,2> -> <4,1>
```

in this move Robot gains 30 percent of the charge hence in the end Battery will have 80 percent of charge.

Comment: And the question is? You expect people to write all your code for you (and for what seems to be a homework)?

Comment: @Gorkk Firstly the question is to find battery cpacity at the end secondly i dont want any code but just an algorithm thirdly its not any homework.

Comment: By the way, the answer is not 80 but 100, as your robot will move (1,2)-(2,3)-(1,4)-(2,4)-(3,4)-(4,4)-(4,3)-(3,2)-(4,1). This will charge the robot's battery by exactly 50 percent.

Comment: @Vesper No, you misinterpreted the question.Robot cant go up again it can go only down

Comment: Okay, then you're right about answer being 80. A-star algorithm can be employed here, it's just your matrix has 3 possible paths out of each node, instead of the normal 8 or 4 for 8-linked grid or 4-linked grid.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem described is a path finding problem with negative movement costs. Especially if your robot's battery can be overcharged. This kind of problems is usually solved by [A-star searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

Comment: How to apply A-star here?Please help

Comment: You have two constraints for the charge, this means the total path cost will be clamped to either (current_charge-100) to (current_charge) interval. Moreover, whenever you receive a path with total cost of (current_charge), don't track any further, as your robot will stop right there.

Comment: Could  you please algoritm in form of pseudocode or a piece of code?

Comment: How about **NO**? You've said you don't need code but the algorithm, here it is.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a simple algorithm:

```
int charge(int x, int y, int battery){
    //Check to see if we've been in this cell with this battery before
    //You'll have to write the functions hasMemorized and memorized to return the value
    //In Java you can use a simple hash map

    if (hasMemorized(x, y, battery)){
        return memorized(x, y, battery);
    }

    if (battery<0 || x<0 || x>=N){
         //We are dead and cannot move
         return -Inf;
    }

    if (y>=M){
        //We have reached our goal; return battery
        return battery;
    }

    //Otherwise, try again
    int val =MAX( charge(x-1, y+1, battery-cost(x-1, y+1)), 
                charge(x,   y+1, battery-cost(x,   y+1)), 
                charge(x+1, y+1, battery-cost(x+1, y+1)));
    setMemorized(x,y,battery, val);

    return val;

  }
```

Then to call:

```
int optimalCharge = 
           MAX( charge(1, 0, 100), 
                charge(2, 0, 100), 
                ... 
                charge(N-1, 0, 100));
```

Comment: Ummm, this algorithm's execution cost is O(exp(M)) total. I say highly inefficient.

Comment: No it's at most O(MNK) where K is the max size of the battery. Note that there is a memorized function, and that y is always increasing.